# Convert Postgre query to Hive/ Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, count, hiveql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE football_teams ( player_id text, name text, team text 
);

INSERT INTO football_teams
VALUES
 ('010', 'Messi', 'Barcelona'),
('007', 'Sancho', 'Dortmund'),
('011', 'Werner', 'Chelsea'),
('001', 'De Gea', 'Manchester United'),
('009', 'Lewandowski', 'Bayern Munich'),
('006', 'Pogba', 'Manchester United'),
('017', 'De Bruyne', 'Manchester City'),
('029', 'Harvertz', 'Bayer Leverkusen'),
('011', 'Werner', 'Liverpool'),
('007', 'Sancho', 'Manchester United'),
('005', 'Upamecano', 'Leipzig'),
('010', 'Messi', 'Manchester City'),
('014', 'Aubameyang', 'Arsenal');
```

I want to a situation where each footballer appears only once in a new table. For instance, Messi appears twice, but I want to  take any occurrence of Messi in the new table.
I am not sure  how to convert it to either Hive or mysql. This is what I want the desired results to look like:

```
player_id   name        team
010         Messi       Barcelona
007         Sancho      Dortmund
011         Werner      Chelsea
001         De Gea      Manchester United
009         Lewandowski Bayern Munich
006         Pogba       Manchester United
017         De Bruyne   Manchester City
029         Harvertz    Bayer Leverkusen
005         Upamecano   Leipzig
014         Aubameyang  Arsenal
```

Comment: I am not sure if you have tested the query but it won't work until you put `player_id` to the order by clause. However does the order you have shown in your expected result matters ?

Comment: *but I want to only take the first occurrence in the new table* The term "first" needs in some rows ordering (visual posessional ordering is fake and cannot be applied for this purposes) which provides ordering uniqueness. In your table the only sorting order which provides this is `ORDER BY team [ASC | DESC]` - but I doubt that this ordering is one you need.

Comment: @Akina I formulated the results. It is not from a query. The first occurrence doesn't really matter as much, I just want each players to appear only once.

Comment: @ learning_2_code, If the order doesn't matter to you then , what is the problem with the answer provided by @Fahmi ? is it not giving you expected result ?

Comment: *The first occurrence doesn't really matter as much, I just want each players to appear only once* If so does you need in `team` column really?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Fahmi 's answer was correct. I just hadn't tested it out yet. I accepted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by name order by cast(player_id as int)) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: `order by cast(player_id as int)` does not provide sorting uniqueness (see sample data) - so the output is not deterministic.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid window function, you can also do -

```
Select player_id, name, max(team) as team
 from football_teams
group by player_id, name;
```

In this approach, you would not need sub-query.